# Only work the first random number. I can't do the cycle again

Tags: assembly, 8051

What I want is a program that generates a random number (0-7), show it in 7-segment display and the user must click that number at buttons on the leds. And the program generates another random number and the cycle repeats. This is the code that I made, but only work the first number.

I'm inexperienced at this site. ;7-segments are the codes os the numbers to show at 7-segments display. ;begin is for testing is any key is pressed. t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7 is for move the number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 to 7-segments

```
;button equ p2.0  
random equ 0 

;7segments  
array equ 30  
mov 30,#11000000b ;cod 0  
mov 31,#11111001b ;cod 1  
mov 32,#10100100b ;cod 2  
mov 33,#10110000b ;cod 3  
mov 34,#10011001b ;cod 4  
mov 35,#10011001b ;cod 5  
mov 36,#10010010b ;cod 6  
mov 37,#10000010b ;cod 7  

;initalize  
mov random,#0  
mov p1,array   
sjmp begin

  begin:  
jnb p2.0,t0  
jnb p2.1,t1  
jnb p2.2,t2  
jnb p2.3,t3  
jnb p2.4,t4  
jnb p2.5,t5  
jnb p2.6,t6  
jnb p2.7,t7  
sjmp begin  

t0:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#0  
jz randomgenerate  
t1:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#1  
jz randomgenerate  
t2:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#2  
jz randomgenerate  
t3:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#3  
jz randomgenerate  
t4:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#4  
jz randomgenerate  
t5:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#5  
jz randomgenerate  
t6:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#6  
jz randomgenerate  
t7:  
mov a,10  
subb a,#7  
jz randomgenerate  
sjmp begin  

randombegin:  
mov random,#10  
sjmp begin  

;random generate  

randomgenerate:  
inc random  
add a, #67  
mov random,a  
mov a, random  
mov b,#50  
div ab  
inc b  
mov a,b  
mov b,#7  
div ab  
mov 15,b  
mov 10,15  


;show segment

mov a,#30  
add a,15  
mov r0,a  
mov p1,@r0  

jb p2.0,t0  
jb p2.1,t1  
jb p2.2,t2  
jb p2.3,t3  
jb p2.4,t4  
jb p2.5,t5  
jb p2.6,t6  
jb p2.7,t7  
ljmp begin
```

Comment: Every problem here is *urgent*.  If there's an answer somebody will come up with it.  Also, you said that your code works for only the first number?  Or does it work for the first cycle of 7?

Comment: The first number that appears on the 7-segment is 0. Clicking the zero it generates the random number and this new number is displayed at 7-segments. But when I click on this number the rest doesn't work.